# Relacionar plantilla twig con controller php en symfony

Tags: php, symfony3, twig

Tengo un método en el controlador sirve para cambiar datos en una tabla.

```
public function bajaServicioAction($idservicio, $idcliente) 
{
  codigo para hacer el cambio en la base de datos
}
```

Por otra parte tengo una plantilla `ficha.html.twig` donde quiero poner un enlace para que ejecute la función antes mencionada

```
<a href="{{ path('clientes_baja_servicio', {'idservicio': servicio.grupo, 
'idcliente': cliente.codigo}) }}"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i></a>
```

Evidentemente no funciona porque no sé cómo hacerlo correctamente, para pasarle esos datos a la función del controlador.

En resumen, necesito pasar unos datos del twig a la función `bajaServicioAction` pero no sé como

Cabe decir que la ruta está configurada para relacione esas dos cosas, pero no sé como pasar los datos de una a la otra.

Edito para mencionar otro detalle importante.

No quiero que vaya a esa ruta, si no que ejecute la acción que en ella se ubica, es decir que recargue la pagina actual con los datos.

Comment: No lo estás haciendo del todo mal, pero hace falta que pongas la definición del la ruta que resuelve la función path, yo revisaría que estés apuntando a ese controlador y si es así, inyecta el objeto Request, y trata de ver si te vienen los valores dentro del request. Puedes poner que versión de symfony usas?

Answer (score 1):

Espero entender bien lo que hace tu controlador, entiendo que quieres dar de baja un servicio usando un enlace no?

De ser así, tienes que tener presente que el proceso de creación de un controlador tiene 3 partes, el controlador, la ruta y el template.

**El controlador:** Este lo tienes correcto.

**La ruta:** aquí creo que es donde tienes el problema, tienes que definir la ruta usando reemplazables para los valores que quieres que lleguen a tu controlador, sería algo así:

```
# config/routes.yaml
clientes_baja_servicio:
    path:      /baja-servicio/{idservicio}/{idcliente}
    controller: XXXX\Controller\XXXXXController::bajaServicio
    requirements:
       idservicio: '\d+'
       idcliente: '\d+'
```

Tienes que reemplazar las XXXX con su correspondiente y estoy asumiendo el path del controller, los requirements validán que las entradas tengan un formato correcto, pero puedes quitarlas si quieres.

**El template:** Yo creo que lo tienes bien, la impresión vía twig de la ruta debería funcionar.

Espero que te ayuden mis comentarios, igual forma te dejo dos enlaces que te podrían complementar mi explicación:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html

Saludos